# Doctrine Custom Query Builder Filters

Tags: function, parameters, doctrine-orm

This is the situation (the code below does not working):

```
if(is_array($filters))
     {
        $f = array();

        foreach($filters as $filter)
        {
            $f[] = $qb->expr()->like("p.tags","'%" . $filter . "%'");
        }

        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orx($f));
     }
```

I need to pass custom/multiple expressions to **orx** function but i don't know how!!

The orx function sistaxe is:

**$qb->expr()->andx($cond1 [, $condN])**

Fixed example (Extracted from doctrine doc's):

```
$qb->add('select', $qb->expr()->select('u'))
->add('from', $qb->expr()->from('User', 'u'))
->add('where', $qb->expr()->orx(
   $qb->expr()->eq('u.id', '?1'),
   $qb->expr()->like('u.nickname', '?2')
))
```

Help please!!

Answer (score 0):

(answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> **Solved,Solution:**
>
> ```
>  if(is_array($filters))
>  {
>     foreach($filters as $filter)
>     {
>         $temp[] = $qb->expr()->like("p.tags","'%" . $filter . "%'");
>     }
>     $qb->andWhere(call_user_func_array(array($qb->expr(),'orx'), $temp));
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Neater solution :)

```
if(is_array($filters))
{
    $f = array();

    $orCondition = $qb->expr()->orX();
    foreach($filters as $filter)
    {
        $orCondition->add($qb->expr()->like("p.tags", "'%" . $filter . "%'"));
    }

    $qb->andWhere($orCondition);
}
```

Or you can do:

```
$orCondition->addMultiple(<conditions_array>);
```